# Is it safe to start the engine after rotating crankshaft by hand(using a torque-wrench)?

Tags: timing-belt, renault, sandero

A quick question before I start my engine.

On a renault sandero (K7m), I took the timing-belt cover off to inspect the condition of my timing-belt.

I then rotated the crankshaft until I could get a better idea of the condition of the timing-belt.

The question is..... Is it safe to switch on the engine at this point?

I didn't mark anything or count the revolutions, but I removed nothing other than the cambelt cover i.e. I did not remove anything on the crankshaft at all. I used a large torque wrench to turn the engine (clockwise), attaching the wrench to the main crank pulley bolt, while inspecting the timing-belt.

Just want to make sure I don't wreck the engine.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are worried about cam timing and lunching the engine, if you've not taken apart any of the cam timing components (belts/cogs/tensioners), you've done nothing to cause you issues. I think the biggest faux pas you've done is using your torque wrench to turn the engine over. Next time, just use a socket & breaker bar (or large ratchet).

Another thing of note here is, you can't really tell the condition of the cam belt by looking at it. You can see obvious things, like if it was starting to fray, but during the life expectancy of the belt, you won't see it do this unless foreign matter has gotten in there. There is a reason manufacturers put a mileage figure on changing your belt and that's so it'll get done well before your engine is close to being in trouble. Do the belt change at recommended intervals and your car won't suffer the fate of [*When Piston Met Valve*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098635/) saga.

Note: Sorry for the "punny" link ... had to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. May I ask... why do you say using a torque wrench is a bad idea to turn the engine?

Comment: @Jim - It's bad for the torque wrench. That's not what it was designed to be used for.

Comment: @Jim a torque wrench is a precision measuring instrument.  It is not a large spanner.  The risk is damaging the torque-wrench's sensors and calibration, therefore its accuracy.   Example - you can hit a long breaker bar with a hammer to drive a socket, but hitting a torque wrench with a hammer will ruin it immediately.   This could be a stand-alone question, we don't seem to have "why not use a torque wrench as a breaker bar?" already.

Comment: Great answer. I don't want to write a competing answer just to add that one best be careful to not turn the engine backwards while manipulating the crankshaft.

Comment: Last time I worked on a car, a "torque wrench" had no sensors or calibration.  https://c.shld.net/rpx/i/s/i/spin/image/spin_prod_665490301??hei=64&wid=64&qlt=50

Comment: @WGroleau - That is what some affectionately call a "bendie" ... and yes, these, too, have a calibration associated with them. As well, you shouldn't use one for everyday tasks which should be relegated to a breaker bar or ratchet.

Comment: For what it's worth, the service history is not complete so I need to do some grokking to try to gather some information.

Odometer is at 108,000 km, which I think translates to 67500 ish miles, with mechs saying the belt should be changed every 56,000 miles. I'm having a bit of trouble sourcing the workshop manual for specs.
... continued

Comment: ... continued ...

Above limitations considered(from answers), the belt looks quite good, after visual inspection. There are no obvious signs the belt has run its course. There are lines on the flat side which show the teeth underneath, but the texture in general is not very smooth. Also, the print is very legible, and I could see one of the white lines(perhaps 50% worn off) when I took the cover off.

So, if I understand, I can keep rotating the belt(using a breaker bar and socket)to get a better picture of the belt? Does it not matter at all where i leave it before starting the vehicle?

Comment: Also, I may have very limited time to use the vehicle due to other, regulatory issues, so I'm hesitant for more than one reason to spend on a belt change. If I can get certainty on regulations, it will make the investment worth it.

Comment: Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, Criggie, psaxton and WGroleau for your input.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 You say one can't really guage  the condition by visually inspecting it, but do you think the belt could have lasted this long 108,000km with out it having been changed?

It is a 2012 model.

Comment: @Jim - Most manufacturers have a maintenance recommendation of 60k miles (100k km) for belt replacement. If there are 108k km on the vehicle right now, I'd suggest you get the belt change regardless of how it looks. Remember, if this is an interference motor (which it most likely is) and the belt goes, the engine goes with it. So, yes, I fully believe your car could have gone 108k km, but it doesn't mean you should let it go much longer.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That sounds like good advice. Do you know if the print on the belt can impart some information as to lifespan?

Comment: I never put stock in it. The downside of doing so is you get a destroyed engine. If I buy a car which I don't know the maintenance history of, I *assume* the belt needs to be changed, unless the total mileage is less than what the first change interval would be considered. Always assume it needs to be done otherwise.